# php code only work if files has been changed

Tags: php, apache, centos, session-variables

The variable in the session only changes if i update the file meaning:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['row']) && isset($_GET['quantity'])) {
    if($_GET['quantity'] != 0) {
      $_SESSION['basket'][$_GET['row']]['barcode']['quantity'] = $_GET['quantity'];
    } else {
      unset($_SESSION['basket'][$_GET['row']]);
    }
  }
?>
```

Changes the quantity first time and then in other tries doesn't.
If I change it to something like:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['row']) && isset($_GET['quantity'])) {
    if($_GET['quantity'] != 0) {
      $num = $_GET['quantity'];
      $_SESSION['basket'][$_GET['row']]['barcode']['quantity'] = $num;
    } else {
      unset($_SESSION['basket'][$_GET['row']]);
    }
  }
?>
```

I save the file in works once and then it stops changing the quantity.
When echoing the variable in the code in shows that it's changed but in the rest of the site it doesn't. the part where it shows doesn't manipulate the variables only prints them.
It seems as if the code works only if the file's been saved and only for the first time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this your whole PHP file? I only ask because you're missing `session_start();` at the top

Comment: Its the part responsible for changing the session. why?

Comment: are you including `session_start();` at the top of your file?

Comment: 9 times out of 10, `session_start();` is secretly hidden and tucked away for safekeeping.

Comment: don't i only session start when creating the session? or do i also need it when editing variables in the existing session?

Comment: Just place `session_start();` at the top of your opening `<?php` tag, and inside all files using sessions and make sure you're not outputting before header. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. @meame69

Comment: Did it. no errors except for "A session had already been started", same problem.